# What is the purpose of Object.assign() in the constructor of a Typescript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

Somewhere along the way, I added a constructor to my `Todo` class:

```
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  complete: boolean = false;
  editMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of the code in the constructor.

My application seems to work both with and without it, but I am hesitant to remove the code

What is the purpose of Object.assign(...) in this constructor?

Comment: Not sure why the answer was deleted, the only part of the answer that was incorrect was apparent "equivalent" code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This a method to easily add the values of the parameters of a class to their respective class fields where a class implements that interface or at least has a partial implantation of that interface.

```
interface IPerson {
  firtName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
  public firtName!: string;
  public lastName!: string;

  constructor(params: IPerson) {
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }
}
```

Your application works because you seem to have implemented this in such a way that the callback value of `values` to also be enough.

The main issue with this Hack is that [Object.assign is not type safe](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/05/14/type-safe-object-merging-2-8/). So using it in this way in a way goes against the point of TypeScript.

If you want to do this in a type safe fashion you are better off using a custom implementation where the type is properly checked. Something like this:

```
type PDM = PropertyDescriptorMap;

export class ClassSAssign<T> {
  constructor(private objectToSpread: T, private klass: T) {}

  private propertyDescriptorOptions = {
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  };

  public apply(): void {
    const map = this.getPropertiesDescriptorMap();
    Object.defineProperties(this.klass, map);
  }

  private getPropertiesDescriptorMap(): PDM {
    return Object.entries(this.objectToSpread).reduce(
      (obj: PDM, entry) => this.getPropertyDescriptorMap(obj, entry),
      {}
    );
  }

  private getPropertyDescriptorMap(obj: PDM, [key, value]: [string, any]): PDM {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [key]: {
        value,
        ...this.propertyDescriptorOptions
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and you can use this utility like this:

```
class Person implements IPerson {
  public firtName!: string;
  public lastName!: string;

  constructor(params: IPerson) {
    new ClassSAssign(params, this).apply();
  }
}
```

If you don't/can't want to use the above, I suggest you at least add some type rigour to protect your class from what values can be passed into it

```
interface IToDo {
  id?: number;
  title?: string;
}

export class Todo implements IToDo {
  public id?: number;
  public title?: string;
  public complete: boolean = false;
  public editMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(values?: IToDo) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @makeitmorehuman,
Can you share the same kind of thing(mixin function) for 2 classes, which can combine 2 + classes togather

Answer (score 3):

`Object.assign` assigns all of the properties of the second argument to the first argument.

What the code does is if you pass an object into the constructor, it will assign those properties to the object that is being made. So for instance:

```
const todo = new Todo({ id: 1, title: 'hello' });
console.log(todo.title); // 'hello'
```

Edit:
Because `Object.assign` is not type-safe, you should probably have the constructor accept something more specific than just an `Object`. I would suggest creating an interface for it.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.assign` has no type checking. An alternative would be:

```
const assign = <T, K extends keyof T>(...args: T[]): T =>
    args.reduce( (result, current) =>
        (Object.keys(current) as K[]).reduce((target, key) => {
            target[key] = current[key];
            return target;
        }, result)
    , args[0])
;
```

Note that if T's properties aren't optional, every object passed in must include every property. If you can guarantee the presence of every property after the function returns, you can pass in the arguments as `Partial<T>`, then coerce the result when you're done.

Comment: One could argue that since `Object.keys` has no type checking either, you are really no closer to type nirvana. You have just added some code to hide the casting better, and added restrictions that may not fit the problems that `Object.assign` is often employed to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Its just combining the two objects `this` and `values`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Its used to create a shallow copy of the object and merge its properties with `this` which is the instance of `Todo`. In your given code `this` target object. Consider the below example

```js
let target = {a:1,b:2};
Object.assign(target,{x:"new prop 1",y:"new prop 2"});
console.log(target)
```

Comment: `is equivalent to` it may be *equivalent*, but you can't do that to `this`, and it's not really *equivalent* for other objects either

Comment: as I said, you can't assign to `this` like that, so that won't work at all - but even when working with other objects, it's not the *same* result at all ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I got the `this` part. But still can't get why both don't work same for other object. Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: @MaheerAli you'd lose non-enumerable properties

Comment: there's also [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7ah2k1c5/) difference ... (look in the console)

Comment: I think zerkms point is probably more important @MaheerAli - but you can see there's a difference (you said equivalent originally, and that's OK, but if someone doesn't know what Object.assign does, then the `{...x}` notation is probably going to confuse them even more :p