# Object constructor from template object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For sports, I try to build a constructor to construct an object based on a template.

Let *template* and *data* two objects where the keys of *data* are a subset of the keys of *template*:

```
const template = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };
const data = { a: 42 };
```

These object literals are examples. The question is how to do it for an arbitrary object of same structure. That is, properties (*keys*) are not know when coding the class constructor.

I should like to write a constructor with which I can construct an Object based on this template with the following expression:

```
foo = new Foo (template, data)
```

where `console.log(foo)` returns for above example // foo = { a: 42 }

That means, the keys present in the Object are to be defined by the template object literal.

So far, I have not found a good way to do so in ES6 (or newer) JS.

**Q:**  How might such a constructor look like? What are good patterns for a class based approach to handle data in such objects?

A hackish way is to have `Object.assign(this, data)` in the constructor. For example:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(template, data) {
    localObject = niftyMergeFunction(template, data);
    Object.assign(this, localObject);
  }
}
```

However, this is bad for several reasons. It is a statement and not an expression. It is not [type-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583832/3842889).

I should like to avoid inheritance, for (i) I avoid <s>learning outdated and controversial practises</s> it and prefer composition. What is more, (ii) *template* can have a common ancestor with *data* but cannot be its parent for conceptual reasons. (consider example: human is animal, cow is animal; don't inherit animal from human and cow from animal, and perhaps another instance of human from animal as well.)

No prototype based designs either, since it appears to be somewhat out of favour at present.

Please note, at this point the task is trivially solved by `foo = Object.assign({}, data)`. However, later i shall use partial assignment `cont Bar = in => Foo(template, in)` and send different data structures instead of object data, such as `bar = new Bar(someFunction(data));` How to curry/partially assign to constructors would be a different question though, please consider this as merely context now.

Comment: I don't understand what "*`returning // foo = { a: 42 }`*" means. Do you mean `new Foo(…)` returns an object `{ a: 42 }`, which then is used in the `foo = ` assignment? What does this have to do with the template?

Comment: "*I avoid learning outdated and controversial practises*" - neither inheritance not prototypes are outdated or controversial. Not sure where you got that from.

Comment: "*at this point the task is trivially solved by `foo = Object.assign({}, data)`*" - then what else are you asking for?

Comment: What do you mean with "constructor"? I don't see a modern JS class or even older prototype constructor function in your post, so it feels like you might be using the wrong term for what you're trying to do, which will likely muddy the waters when it comes to getting a good answer.

Comment: @Bergi ... trivially solved... se the context that follows. It doesn't create a structure of the same class. Why bother with OO stuff at all? Let's see some people like it, and I shall give it a try. The way I should deal purely functional with object literals seems a bit clumsy. Thus I'm working on integrating OO tools for data.

Comment: You can extend the use case quite a bit further. Stipulate you have an external input json with object properties. Then you need to create a class based on properties unknown at time of writing your code. Plus you need `class { constructor {...} }` patterns.

Comment: @gschenk It's still unclear what effect the `template` should have. All you currently do is load the `data` into a different object.

Comment: @gschenk "*you need to create a class based on properties unknown at time of writing your code*" - no, you never need to do that. If you don't know your properties, you cannot write any methods for them, and that means you don't need a `class` for it. Just keep the plain data of unknown structure as data, treating it like a collection.

Comment: @Bergi I thought I can write methods generic for a class like this:
`someMethod: function (f) { return Object.keys(this).map( f )` It is the easy way for me to keep my data in object literals and write pure functions to return them. I'm a bit surprised though, most coding is done with generic functions, preferably variadic. But classes need their `this.foo = foo` spelled out? If you got half a score of keys, they are in source? Shouldn't such long lists get moved out into jsons? Then only composed into objects with their methods and other stuff?

Comment: Yes, properties should go in the code, to spell them out explicitly and ensure they don't collide with the method names. You cannot guarantee that when they come from some external json. I'm not sure what you mean by "generic functions, preferably variadic". If your functions are generic enough to not care about specific property names, then they shouldn't become methods anyway. Also, half a score of properties sounds too many for a single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and straight forward after all to have properties in a constructor in class syntax based on arguments passed to the constructor. Mapping a function along the lines of `a => this[a]` onto an array of the property keys does it. In the snippet is an example where there is also an assignment to the property.

```js
// example objects
const someObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0,
};

const otherObject = {
  a: 1,
  c: 137,
  d: 42,
};

class Test {
  constructor(template, data) {
    Object.keys(template).map(a => {
      this[a] = data[a] ? data[a] : template[a];
      return null;
    });
    Object.seal(this);
  }
}

const test = new Test(someObject, otherObject);
console.log(test);
```

As a nice addition its new objecst already has an `Object.seal` applied during construction.

**further remarks**

- If one cannot use `Object.seal` yet, inserting `Object.freeze` at the end of the property generating function will help with a deep freeze.
- <s>I cannot get my actual purpose for this working:</s> that is partial application of the `template` object. The idea was to have new monovariate class constructor functions. *fixed*

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an object-based language. Classes in JavaScript are mostly syntactic sugar. If, like me, you don't like class-oriented object orientation, then you do not have to use it.

If you want to write a function to combine objects with arbitrary properties, there is nothing "hackish" with using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

If you want to prevent further modification of the result, you can use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

I think the first question you need to ask yourself is "do I really need to do this?" Are you trying to make JavaScript look and work like Haskell? Is it worth it? It is possible, however, you have a good reason for doing what you want to do.

The following code might be of use.

```js
const curry = (fn, acc = [], cont) =>
      cont = (...args) => 
        (acc = [...acc, ...args], 
          args.length ? cont : fn(...acc))

const mapObject = (mapProperty, to, from) => 
    (Object.keys(to).forEach(k => 
        (isObject(to[k]) && isObject(from[k])) 
            ? mapObject(mapProperty, to[k], from[k])
            : mapProperty(to, from, k)), to)

const isObject = (o) => o !== null && typeof o === 'object'
const deepClone = (o) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))
const mapProperty = (to, from, key) => (from.hasOwnProperty(key) && (to[key] = from[key]))
const deepAssign = mapObject.bind(null, mapProperty)

const factory = curry((template, ...data) => 
                    data.reduce((acc, datum) => 
                        deepAssign(acc, datum), deepClone(template)))

const template = { a: '', b: '', c: { d: '' }, e: '', f: '' }
const myFactory = factory(template)
const o1 = { a: 'a'}
const o2 = { b: 'b' }
const o3 = { c: { d: 'd' } }
const o4 = { f: 'f' }
const o5 = { g: 'g' }

console.log(myFactory(o1)(o2)(o3)(o4)(o5)())
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, however, this only works when you know the properties `a, b` beforehand. I try to create a constructor for an arbitrary set of properties. So that it works for `[a, b, c]` as well as `[x, y, z]`.

Comment: I shall try to make the question a little clearer about this.

Comment: I want to use the Class to have new objects with different content but the keys of the template object. By currying the constructor I can avoid having to rely on globals and import in modules. I'm not far enough, but maybe I can use the Class/constructor to create immutable data objects from pure functions. However, bear with me, I'm new to this and find separation of concern, separation of functions and data somewhat difficult. My comfort zone would be writing pure functions to format nested arrays of objects into object literals. Almost like data structures with lists and tuples in Haskell).

Comment: JaaScript does not have strong or static typing, so you'll need to use convention. If you want to simply combine objects, then a function like the one in my answer will suffice. If you really want immutability then JavaScript does have a mechanism to freeze objects, but it's rarely used IME.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen your edit before I replied. That is indeed something similar to what I am doing. However, I expected to find some use for all the nice things `class {}` may bring. ps.: A pitty about the typing. The lack of a good type system is so often an obstacle.

Comment: There are plusses and minuses to JavaScript's type system. I actually prefer JavaScript to other languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
  constructor (data, template) {
    this.data = data
    this.template = template
  }
  setTemplate (template) {
    this.template = template
  }
  get value () {
    let output = {}
    output[this.data] = this.template
    return output
  }
}
```

Edited to reflect feedback in comment

Comment: Don't use a class constructor if you're going to `return` an object